# Filter prometheus results by metric value, not by label value

Tags: grafana, prometheus

Because [Prometheus topk returns more results than expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783424/prometheus-topk-returns-more-results-than-expected), and because https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/586 requires client-side processing that has not yet been made available via https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/7664, I'm trying to pursue a different near-term work-around to my similar problem.

In my particular case most of the metric values that I want to graph will be zero most of the time. Only when they are above zero are they interesting.

I can find ways to write prometheus queries to filter data points based on the value of a *label*, but I haven't yet been able to find a way to tell prometheus to return time series data points only if the value of the *metric* meets a certain condition. In my case, I want to filter for a value greater than zero.

Can I add a condition to a prometheus query that filters data points based on the metric value? If so, where can I find an example of the syntax to do that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Filtering is done with the [comparison operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators), for example `x > 0`.

Comment: Yes, and I can find ways to reference the value of a label in place of x in the example, but I have not been able to figure out how to reference the value of the metric itself.

Comment: For example, consider a metric named items_in_queue, with a label queue_name.  I want to show a graph of how many items are in each queue, but if a queue had zero items in it for the entire duration of my graph, I don't want its name to show up in the legend.  And if most of my queues are empty most of the time, I don't want a different collection of zero-depth queue names to show up in my results for every sample.

What would a query look like to show me topk items_in_queue, but only when items_in_queue > 0?  How do I reference the metric instead of a label?

Comment: I imagine it would look something like

`items_in_queue{ _something_ > 0 }`

but what do I put in place of _something_?

Comment: What do you mean "reference the metric instead of a label"? Labels are strings, you can't do math on them.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something even more basic. I've looked at both https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/operators and https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/examples/, but I can't seem to find any example that shows how/where those binary comparison operators fit into a query. Can you point me to an example of a complete query that shows a binary comparison operator in context?

Comment: https://www.robustperception.io/combining-alert-conditions/ Per above, `x > 0` is a complete PromQL expression.

Comment: So - to elaborate a bit...  If I wanted a grafana graph that shows a time series of queue depth for all queues (items_in_queue metric) on a particular host (labeled by host_name) but only those queues whose items_in_queue metric was greater than zero, that query would look something like...

`items_in_queue{host_name=~"myhost"} > 0`.

The filter on the label value goes inside the `{}`, and the filter based on the metric value goes after the `{...}`.  Is that the way it works?

Comment: If you're using the Grafana UI and you're a total n00b like me, then you do this by either a) adding an "Operation" set to Binary Operations > Greater Than or b) just switch the view to "Code" in the upper right to manually edit the raw query and add `> 0` at the end.

Answer (score 33):

If you're confused by [brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83591/brian-brazil)['s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46697834/401059): The result of filtering with a comparison operator is not a boolean, but the filtered series. E.g.

```
min(flink_rocksdb_actual_delayed_write_rate > 0)
```

Will show the minimum value above 0.

In case you actually want a boolean (or rather 0 or 1), use something like

```
sum (flink_rocksdb_actual_delayed_write_rate >bool 0)
```

which will give you the greater-than-zero count.

Answer (score 6):

This can be solved with [subqueries](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/):

```
count_over_time((metric > 0)[5m:10s])
```

The query above would return the number of `metric` data points greater than 0 over the last 5 minutes.

This query may return inaccurate results depending on the relation between the second arg in square brackets (aka `step` for the inner query) and the real interval between raw samples (aka `scrape_interval`):

- If the `step` exceeds `scrape_interval`, them some samples may be missing during the calculations. In this case the query will return lower than expected result.
- If the `step` is smaller than the `scrape_interval`, then some samples may be counted multiple times. In this case the query will return bigger than expected result.

So it is recommended setting the `step` to `scrape_interval` in order to get accurate results.

P.S. The issues mentioned above are solved in VictoriaMetrics - Prometheus-like monitoring system I work on. It provides [count_gt_over_time()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_gt_over_time) function, which ideally fits this case. For example, the following [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) query returns **the exact** number of raw samples with values greater than 0 over the last 5 minutes:

```
count_gt_over_time(metric[5m], 0)
```

Comment: For others: make sure to include two time ranges within the brackets, otherwise you'll get an error. Took me a bit to figure that out.