# Calculation of process execution time in grafana based on start/end time and current time

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics, promql

I need to show the running time of a process in grafana. I get the process start time as timestamp from prometheus and subtract it from the current timestamp: `time() - start_time_gauge`. Then I format it as duration in grafana like `1d 07:22:01`, it works as expected.

But this is only relevant when the process is running right now. But if process execution has finished, then completion time is written by server to `end_time_gauge` metric (which is initially 0) and duration must be calculated as `(end_time_gauge ? end_time_gauge : time()) - start_time_gauge`. But the problem is that PromQL has no ternary operators, and when I try to use the recommended way `(end_time_gauge or time()) - start_time_gauge`, I get an error:
`parse error: set operator "or" not allowed in binary scalar expression`.

Is there any way to achieve the desired result? Perhaps, I could use capabilities of grafana itself instead of using PromQL when mapping, for example, using transformations to conditionally combine several queries or something like that.

Also, I can modify the metrics sent from server to simplify the mapping on the grafana side. But only within reasonable limits, writing current timestamp to `end_time_gauge` every second doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two queries: one for running processes and secind one for finished processes. You can use Grafana merge transformation to merge results from these queries into one, which then can be visualized by selected panel.

Comment: Okay, let's assume that running processes have `end_time_gauge = 0`. The finished processes have a value greater than 0. But how to build two separate queries, one for the running ones and one for the finished ones?

Comment: @WindBridges "where" condition `end_time_gauge == 0` and `end_time_gauge != 0`

Comment: I'm querying metrics from Prometheus, PromQL doesn't support WHERE, as far as I understand.

Comment: @WindBridges doc is your friend (or SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46697754/filter-prometheus-results-by-metric-value-not-by-label-value)