# filter range vector without knowing scrape interval

Tags: promql, victoriametrics, metricsql

I'm trying to figure out how to filter range vector correctly and then use it to select other metric values and do some aggregation over it, ie. something like

```
count_over_time((metric_a and (metric_b > 95)[30m])
```

The issue I do not understand is if I do not put scrape interval after lookbehind windows into square brackets, I do not get all values of `metric_a`, just - as it seems - the first and the last one.

As I learnt in other [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46697754/filter-prometheus-results-by-metric-value-not-by-label-value), and after some experimentation, I ended up with this

```
count_over_time((metric_a and (metric_b > 95))[30m])[30m:10s])
```

and then I (seem to) get all values I want. The scrape interval I specify should match the real, but I may not know it. How can I just get all values from a range vector and filter them without knowing/specifying scrape interval?