# Display table for series with label's occurrence count greater than N in Prometheus

Tags: grafana, prometheus, promql

In Prometheus, given below metric definition, how do I render a table for top 5 recurring devices part of the metric series?

```
top_5_noisy_devices:

    { "device" : "1234", "type" : "foo"}
    { "device" : "1234", "type" : "foo"}
    { "device" : "1234", "type" : "foo"}
    { "device" : "2345", "type" : "foo"}
    { "device" : "4231", "type" : "foo"}
    { "device" : "4354", "type" : "foo"}
```

I want to render a table in Grafana for the above labels to show that device 1234 is the noisy device in the selected time duration.
I tried topk operator but it renders more than 3. ( I see 100's of rows in table instead of just 3) 
https://www.robustperception.io/graph-top-n-time-series-in-grafana claims to support topk in Grafana. But I fail to understand how to adapt it to a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used below approach to display a table.

- Define a variable **interval** with few static values (Example)
  [image]
- Add a Panel in Grafana (either as table or a Pie Chart of your choice) and used below query

> topk(5,round(increase(top_5_noisy_devices{type="Foo"}[$interval])))

- legend format as {{ device }}
- Format as -> Time series
- legend format as {{ device }}
- Select Instant check box

[image]

[image]

And selecting any interval dropdown using the variables fetches the topk data for the specific period.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems prometheus does not support such a feature.
References:

1. [Prometheus topk returns more results than expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783424/prometheus-topk-returns-more-results-than-expected)
2. https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/586

Answer (score 0):

You can [now use the `@` modifier](https://prometheus.io/blog/2021/02/18/introducing-the-@-modifier/) to achieve this:
`top_5_noisy_devices and topk(5, count_over_time(top_5_noisy_devices[$__range] @ end()))`

Note this uses [the grafana `$__range` variable](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#__range) to get the range of the table.